# Bus schedule Pereira to Filandia

Tags: buses, colombia

I plan to go from Pereira (Airport if possible) to Filandia, preferably by bus. Is this possible? Can anyone point me to the bus schedule?

Comment: was there a better alternative, or did you have to go all the way to Armenia first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should go to Armenia (1 hour from Pereira) and then go to Filandia. [Here](http://www.terminalarmenia.com/?id=15) you can find Armenia to Filandia schedules and rates. There are regular services every 15-30 min from 6am to 8pm.

Expect the same schedules from Pereira to Armenia, they are two major cities in the zone and are plenty of options to do that route.